Отключить DOM IntelliSense для Node
Вопрос
При попытке печатать в Node что-то IntelliSense в VSCode выдает подсказки из DOM (такие как document, HTMLElement, EventTarget...).

Как можно отключить подсказки от DOM при использовании Node?

Возможно вам нужно нормально настроить tsconfig

@OliverPatterson где его настроить? В проете нет никаких config-ов.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/intro-to-js-ts.html и https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#overview

@nörbörnën я нашел информацию об этом вот тут, но там не сказано как отключить DOM. Написано, что можно отключить, но как не написано. Поигрался с настройками... изменилось все кроме DOM.

по первой ссылке то, что мы имели ввиду. напишите "lib": ["ESNext"] и рестартуйте ide (хотя обычно рестарт не нужен)

@nörbörnën написал и в TS и в JS, перезагрузил. Без изменений. ¯\(ツ)/¯


эти файл должны быть в корне проекта, а не в .vscode. 2) для vscode достаточно jsconfig.json


@nörbörnën спасибо, можете оставить как ответ.

мне лень. напишите сами, я поправлю, если что

Ответ
В корневом каталоге создаем jsconfig.json. В нем меняем compilerOptions.lib. IntelliSense тогда будет использовать те библиотеки, которые отмечены в нем. В нашем случае jsconfig.json будет таким:
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "lib": [
            "ESNext",
        ],
    },
}


Подробнее...
